# How to configure unique public IP addresses for multiple LXC containers?

Tags: digital-ocean, lxc, lxd

I would like to have multiple LXC containers on my VPS, each with their own public IP address, accessible through the internet (so that I can run web-accessible services within each LXC).

I used LXD to create the LXC, and I am running this on Ubuntu on a digital ocean droplet.

I know that I could use a reverse proxy (like nginx or haproxy) to route particular domains to containers, but I would prefer that each container had its own IP address, so that I could simply use my DNS registrar to route the correct domains to the correct IP address (and not have to worry about configuring SSL certificates for the reverse proxy).

Any guidance on the easiest/best way to do this is appreciated.

Comment: add the ips to the [ipv4.routes](https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/networks/) option on the bridge, then create a [nic device](https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instances/#type-nic) which uses the ip then attach it to the container

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for this. from reading [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Proxmox/comments/awjrvn/proxmox_on_digitalocean_testing_environement/) it looks to me like DO will not allow me to have multiple public ipv4 IP addresses, which I think means this will not work?

Comment: I know a guy, who used proxmox and then macvlan'ed the ips which he got from a local ISP into the containers but the downside is the container can no longer talk to other containers, but yeah I'm not sure you can get/buy additional ips on DO other than the floating ones. Personally, I've built a LXD control panel which I only need to enter the domain/s into a text box and it creates the nginx config which upstreams to the container and letsencrypt certs for the domains, then I put all the domains on cloudflare, so its SSL all the way through, doing all this manually would be abit of a pain

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dcAOVN0

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that sounds like a useful tool. is the code for your lxd control panel available somewhere?